# Scala Load balancing and retrieval

Tags: scala, mpi, akka, actor

I am trying to implement parallel dijkstra algorithm in scala. I have a big adjacency matrix and I want to divide the work for say 100 indexes to each actor.

Is there any way to divide the work load to different actors like we do in MPI (using MPI_Scatter()

Is there any way to reduce/broadcast the result like in MPI (MPI_AllReduce/ MPI_Broadcast).

One brute way I can think of is to pass the whole matrix and just pass the index to each actor, but that would defeat the purpose of using actors. Besides, if I do like this, it would not be good idea if the actors are remotely located.

Any suggestion would be of great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Akka routing is what you are looking for: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html

The broadcast or scatter/gather based routers would probably be what you are looking for to do your 'brute' force parallel algorithm.

However, you are right; this 'brute' attempt partially defeats the purpose of using actors. There do exist already parallelized versions of Dijkstra's algorithm. Based on a quick glance, it looks to be mainly divide and conquer based algorithms where the graph is partitioned into sub-graph-tasks where cross actor communication and broadcasting is key. This definitely sounds like the kind of problem that Akka was built for.

Comment: Akka routing only routes the messages to the actors. It does not provide the option of dividing the payload to actors or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: No, you are correct, the routing does not take care of dividing the payload. That is an implementation task for someone else (eg a parent actor). When the payload is divided, you can then send each sub-payload to the router n times. You treat a router as a single actor, but behind it are m routed actors, which could potentially be doing the same computation per sub-payload (ie divide and conquer or a Mapper in MapReduce).